# underscore.js TypeError: Object ... has no method 'push'

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I would like to append a new value into each office array:

```
{
  "name" : "HQ",
  "office" : [ 
    {
      "name" : "Office1",
      "_id" : ObjectId("54671a5e82092cbc3f1e6104")
    }, 
    {
      "name" : "Office2",
      "_id" : ObjectId("54671a5e82092cbc3f1e6103")
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to do this using underscorejs:

```
var offices = [];
_.each(doc.offices, function(value){
  offices.push(value.push({"distance": distanced}));
}
```

but I get `TypeError: Object ... has no method 'push'`.

Is there any faster way to do it using underscorejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values being passed into the `_.each` function are objects such as `{name: ...}`, so you're trying to push an object onto an object. Do you want to do something like the following?

```
var offices = [];
_.each(doc.office, function(value) {
  value.distance = distanced;
  offices.push(value);
});
```

Comment: the distance value is not in the array, I need to append into it.

Comment: I think you may be confused about objects vs. arrays. Objects are the things in `{}`, and you add properties to them, but don't push onto them. Arrays are the things in `[]`, and you push onto them, but don't (normally) add properties to them. Which array are you saying the distance value is not in, that you want it to be? It might be helpful if you would provide an exact desired output.